# how to perform parameter binding for in clause for Collection in JPQL without using JOIN?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

Here is the data modelling scenario:

For illustrative purposes consider this simple data model:

ManyToMany From Project to Department

ManyToMany From Project to Employee

Consider this entitiy:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries( {
@NamedQuery(name = "project.getProjectByDepartmentAndEmployee", 
query = "SELECT p from Project p WHERE (:dept) in p.department and (:emp) in p.employees"),
})
public class ConfigFile extends BaseUpdatableEntity implements Serializable {

    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Department> departments;


    @ManyToMany
    private List<Employee> employees;

}
```

in My Dao Layer, I want to execute the following:

```
public Project getProject(Department dept, Employee emp){
       Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("project.getProjectByDepartmentAndEmployee");
        query.setParameter("dept", dept)
             .setParameter("emp",emp);
            return (UserSession) query.getResultList().get(0);
}
```

The problem I see with NamedQueryConstruction above.
How will I bind parameters in Where clause on left side.

Thanks for help

**NOTE**

Answer below will work. but I am looking for a solution without using JOIN if possible

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your JPQL query to:

```
SELECT p 
from Project p 
inner join p.department d
inner join p.employees e
WHERE d = :dept and e = :emp
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I was thinking if there is a way to get this without using JOIN

Comment: yes, it did and I know it will work. I am looking to get solution without using JOIN